# Resizing divs proportionally in a webapp

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm trying to create a webapp that can be resized (just like we resize windows in our OS), I know i can easily do this using an absolute position and the resize both property, but I want it to be resized proportionally and have a maximum limit, I tried and googled this but no "precise" answer, Thank you for any help :p !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I might get what you mean now, you could use jQuery UI instead of CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="re_size_me">text in div</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#re_size_me{
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#re_size_me" ).resizable({
      aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
       maxHeight: 300,
      maxWidth: 300,
      minHeight: 50,
      minWidth: 50
    });
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52u24bhd/)**

You can read more here: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is exactly the answer you are after but you can use the min-height, max-height, and same for width and also use % with vw to keep ratio:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
    margin 0;
    padding 0;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.box {
    width:20%;
    height:20vw;
    min-width:100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin:1%;
    background:DodgerBlue ;
    float:left;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4mmwe17r/1/)**